# Regular expression to allow 1 digit at beginning of 5 letter group

Tags: php, regex

I currently have this regular expression:

`/(^| )[a-z]{5}-[a-z]{5}( |$)/i`

start of string or space, 5 letters, literal dash, 5 letters, space or end of string, case insensitive.

This finds a string that looks like this: `pejnd-zxdgn`

I need to allow the first letter only to be a digit instead of a letter.

How do I write this?

**Edit:**
To clarify

should match: `pejnd-zxdgn` or `7ejnd-zxdgn`

Should not match `7pejnd-zxdgn` or `7ejn-zxdgn` or p7ejnd-zxdgn

Comment: Do you want the whitespace at the beginning or end to be optional? Is that why you used `(^| )`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a pattern for digit before the `[a-z]` part. And change the quantifier to `{4}`:

```
/(^| )[0-9][a-z]{4}-[0-9][a-z]{4}( |$)/i
```

---

After your update, you just want the first character to be digit or character. Also, you can use word boundaries - `\b` at the beginning and the end, as noted in comments. So, change your regex to:

```
/\b[a-z0-9][a-z]{4}-[a-z]{5}\b/i
```

Comment: But I want to still accept 5 letters in that place, so maybe `/(^| )[0-9a-z][a-z]{4}-[0-9][a-z]{4}( |$)/i` ?

Comment: @TecBrat. Now I don't understand your question. You said, you want first letter only to be digit? May be you should add some sample valid and invalid input.

Comment: @TecBrat Yes. You can use `\b` instead of the space and/or anchors too: `/\b[0-9a-z][a-z]{4}-[0-9][a-z]{4}\b/i`

Comment: You led me to a solution that works: `(^| )[0-9a-z][a-z]{4}-[a-z]{5}( |$)` Thanks.

Comment: @TecBrat. `|` is not needed inside the character class.

Comment: @RohitJain I realized that and removed it aleady. Thanks.